# Is right shifting unsigned types in c++ implementation defined

Tags: c++, bit-shift, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I know that right shifting a signed type in c++ (such as an `int`) is implementation defined: some machines will perform a logical right shift, and other machines will perform an arithmetic right shift.

I made the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 1 << 31;  // It is an unsigned int on purpose
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        std::cout << std::bitset<(32)>(a >> i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

and the output was

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
01000000000000000000000000000000
00100000000000000000000000000000
...
00000000000000000000000000000010
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

which means that my machine performs logical right shifts to an `unsigned int`. I was wondering if this is always the case: is right shifting an `unsigned int` (or any other unsigned types) implementation defined, or is right shifting an `unsigned int` always a logical right shift?

Comment: What would be the difference between arithmetic and logical shifts on an *unsigned* integer? Also, since C++20, right-shift on *signed* is no longer implementation-defined [and **will** be an arithmetic shift](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift).

Comment: "[The value of E1 >> E2 is E1/(2 to the power E2), rounded down.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.shift#3)".